# SNMP : Community Name is "public", how I can change it?

Tags: snmp, zebra-printer

I want to change `SNMP community Name` in Zebra ZM600 printer from public to private for ex:

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c public "address IP" enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5
```

when I walk the `MIB tree` I use `public` like a name of community , put I want change it to `private` or other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I found the solution for this issue

**first** I create file with `ZPL II` commands `test.zpl` inside the file I wrote this command :

```
^XA 
^NN,,,test,, 
^XZ
```

**second** I send this file to the printer via FTP with command line:

```
c:> put c:\test.zpl
```

**third** I restart the printer by `~JR` command.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c TEST "address IP" enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5
```